# functional way to get both previous value and new value from ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java, scala, concurrenthashmap

I need to get both previous and new value from Java ConcurrentHashMap (in Scala code). To keep it thread-safe I use `compute` block which returns only new value. Is it possible to get both new and previous value without using var with initial null? Below my current solution:

```
  map: ConcurrentHashMap[String, Object] = new ConcurrentHashMap

  def foo = {
    var previousValue: Object = null

    val newValue = map.compute("key", (_, value) => {
      previousValue = Option(value).getOrElse(initialValue)
      setNewValue(previousValue)
     }
    )

    (previousValue, newValue)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

No. It is not possible with current version of [ConcurrentHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.KeySetView.html).

Answer (score -1):

> *"... I need to get both previous and new value from Java ConcurrentHashMap (in Scala code). ..."*

Here is a solution in *Java*, that you can port.

A somewhat un-contemporary approach; traverse the *key-set* with a *[ListIterator](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ListIterator.html)*.

```java
Map<String, Integer> m = new HashMap<>() {{
    put("A", 1);
    put("B", 2);
    put("C", 3);
    put("D", 4);
    put("E", 5);
}};
List<String> l = new ArrayList<>(m.keySet());
ListIterator<String> i = l.listIterator();
String x, y = i.next();
while (i.hasNext()) {
    x = i.next();
    System.out.printf("x = {'%s': %s}, ", x, m.get(x));
    System.out.printf("y = {'%s': %s}%n", y, m.get(y));
    if (i.hasNext()) y = x;
}
```

```
x = {'B': 2}, y = {'A': 1}
x = {'C': 3}, y = {'B': 2}
x = {'D': 4}, y = {'C': 3}
x = {'E': 5}, y = {'D': 4}
```

Comment: The whole point of the question is to do it in a functional/Scala way. That is without mutability and possibly loops.

Comment: This is not a functional way as @GaëlJ mentioned and you use HashMap instead of ConcurrentHashMap so this is not thread-safe solution. The point is to include all logic in one compute block to avoid race-condition.

Comment: @Reilas I will. And thank you for your willingness to help, I appreciate it.

Comment: This code does not seem related to the question asked either. "Previous" in the question refers to the previous value associated with the key, not the previous entry.